# How to test angular component with div as ViewChild

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jestjs

I've a angular component as shown below. I want to write jasmine tests for the initMyChart() function below. I'm not able initialize library as I don't have the viewChild div element accessible in test.

```
component.html
<div #myId></div>

component.ts
export class MyComponent implements OnInit{

  chart: ChartLibrary;

  @ViewChild('myId') myIdDiv: ElementRef

  constructor(){}

  initMyChart(){
   //Using some library which takes the div as input to initialize
   this.chart = new Chart(this.myIdDiv.nativeElement)
  }
}
```

When I try to run the test I get following error

```
console.error node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext (without installing the canvas npm package)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think use can use fixture.debugElement. For example:

```
const el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#myId');
```

And you can follow this link: [enter link description here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/components/).